# Returning data from embedded document in laravel+mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

i have a document with the following structure

```
db.projects.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("587eb04ec5d281280d9244ed"),
    "root" : "Main Boards",
    "access" : "Public",
    "folders" : [
        {
            "foldersname" : "PROJECTS"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("587eb052c5d281280d9244ee"),
    "root" : "Shared Boards",
    "access" : "Public"
}
```

I successfully loaded the data in a variable. i can display the field 'root' contents in the blade view but i cant display the field 'foldersname'. here is my code below.

```
@foreach($structures as $structure)    
<a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">{{$structure->root}}</a>

          @foreach($structure as $folders)

            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">{{$folders->foldersname}}</a>
          @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I get the following error. i have been looking for solutions since 2 days. i have applied solutions from laravel forum and here but in vain. Can someone guide me to the right solution. thanks

> Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: for the second foreach Try this `@foreach($structure->folders as $folder)<a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">{{$folder->foldersname}}</a>@endforeach`

Comment: @Amani it does not work. still getting the above error.

Comment: Try this : `@foreach($structure->folders as $folder) @if (isset($folder->foldersname) ) <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">{{$folder->foldersname}}</a>@endforeach`

Comment: @Amani i now get the following error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: can you return your object (in the Controlleur) instead of returning the view and post it in your question?

Comment: @Amani how do i do that. am still new to laravel and mongodb. thanks :) heres the code for the controller `class ProjectController extends Controller
{
  public function getDashboard()
  {
    $structures = Project::all();
    return view('dashboard', ['structures' => $structures]);
  }
}`

Comment: `class ProjectController extends Controller { public function getDashboard() { $structures = Project::all(); return $structures } }`

Comment: @Amani `[{"_id":"587eb04ec5d281280d9244ed","root":"Main Boards","access":"Public","folders":[{"foldersname":"PROJECTS"}]},{"_id":"587eb052c5d281280d9244ee","root":"Shared Boards","access":"Public"}]`

Comment: Ok I see Try this : `@if (isset($structure->folders))@foreach($structure->folders as $folder) @if(isset($folder->foldersname) ) <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">{{$folder->foldersname}}</a> @endif @endforeach @endif`

Comment: @Amani the view loaded successfully but the contents for the <a> is not loaded. :(

Comment: I put everything in an answer, can you check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
 @foreach($structures as $structure)    
    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">{{$structure->root}}</a>
    @if (isset($structure->folders))
       @foreach($structure->folders as $folder)
          @if(isset($folder['foldersname']) )      
             <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">{{$folder['foldersname']}} </a>
          @endif
       @endforeach
    @endif
 @endforeach
```

Comment: `{{$structure->root}}` gets loaded but not `{{$folder->foldersname}}`

Comment: can you do a small test, just before you first foreach loop add this  `{{ $structures[0]->folders[0]->foldersname }} ` and see If you have some output.

Comment: stil getting this error `Trying to get property of non-object `

Comment: have you any function in your `Project` model  called `folders` or `foldersname` ?

Comment: i do not have any function that call folders in the Project Model

Comment: Ok once again can you please add this line outside the foreach loop I mean in the top of your view  `@php
var_dump($structures[0]->folders); @endphp`

Comment: does not work.. can you propose a new way how can i do this?

Comment: what is the outout you get from the var_dump?  (the code I post in the answer is tested and it is working there is something else wrong)

Comment: i still get `trying to get property of non object` . i get it that the contents of the 'folders' field is an array. but even if i try folders[0]['foldersname'] i get nothing

Comment: if you use `@php var_dump($structures[0]->folders);@endphp` and comment the rest of the code you will be able to see the content of your array.(comment every thing in your view except this line please)

Comment: i got this array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'foldersname' => string 'PROJECTS' (length=8)

Comment: That proves that the above answer is rigth can you try `{{$folder->foldersname}}` instead of `<a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">{{$folder->foldersname}}</a>` just remove the `a` element and keep the rest, maybe you have some css or javascript  issues.

Comment: is this http://laravel.io/bin/vBDEK your current code ? This is so wrong !!

Comment: I have one last suggestion .. change the last if staetment to this `@if(isset($folder['foldersname']) ) {{$folder['foldersname']}} @endif`

Comment: It works :D thank you very much for being so patient with me. You are my savior.

Comment: I didnt notice that $structures[0]->folders is an array (dispite that I asked you to var_dump this LOL) .. so I access it the wrong way.. You are welcome. I will update the answer.

Comment: sorry :) was away